# Running @gen.coroutine synchronous in Tornado and Flask

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, tornado

I've got a problem with asynchronous connection in Tornado. I'd like to make proxy that get page body by accessing Flask endpoint (/async/...). Then it should asynchronously get content of that page. But how can I do it? There is a snippet that I've already written. It prints response.body well but how can I return it in proxyAsync to display it on webpage?

```
@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    print('------------------')
    print(response.body)
    print('------------------')
    raise gen.Return(response.body)

@proxy_service.route('/async/<path:url>', methods=methodsHTTP)
def proxyAsync(url):
    # Send request
    response = fetch_coroutine(url)

    return jsonify({})
```

Answer (score 0):

@gen.coroutine returns a gen.Future instance. This needs to be handled. Otherwise the tornado http_client fetch won't be completed by anything.

You should be able to make this snippet work by doing something like:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
def proxyAsync(url):
    response = IOLoop.current().run_sync(fetch_coroutine(url))
    # I presume you wanted to return the response.
    return jsonify(response)
```

You're not going to get any benefit from the asynchronous http_fetch anyway, because your app is based on Flask.

Is there a specific reason you want to use Flask and Tornado? Tornado's web framework is easy enough to use, and then your asynchronous http_fetch would sit nicely with the main application's IOLoop.